# Error while extracting the zip file

Tags: asp.net, wpf, windows, dll, dotnetzip

I am facing a problem while extracting some windows .xap, it gives me error show in the image below..

[image: Erroe]

I have tried to replace the current .dll witih new dotnetzip .dll , but still facing same error..
Any Suggestions ??

Comment: Where's the popup from? Have you tried opening it with WinRAR/7zip/other zip program? Your question is lacking detail.

Comment: Well popup is from "WP7-3MktPlace", after downloading xap the application extract the file and patching is done...but i am facing this error at time of extraction..

Comment: actually that application had a dll file named "Ionic.Zip.dll",this file is of dotnetzip API, that is used to prepare application for zipping file etc. That dll version was old so i replaced it with new dll...but same problem..

Comment: Well, now that it is in the ZIP format, you might want to open the XAP file in a zip program to see if the file is broken. Did you try that?

Comment: i have tried to open it with programs like winrar/7zip...but unable to open...

Comment: Okay if you cannot open the file with winrar or 7zip, then we'll have to assume that the file is broken. Have you tried creating a zip file of your own and have the program work with that?